# How to solve "Your app is vulnerable to Intent Redirection."

Tags: android, google-play, android-security

I've uploaded an app to Play Store which was working fine till version 9 and I'm not able to figure out what is causing this issue.  These are the libraries that I used in the app.

1. implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.1'
2. implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:2.4.0' // Image Picker
3. implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.2' // PayTM

Comment: I'm Stuck with this too -

Comment: They have not provided any more details on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest version of App-invoke SDK which has been provided on developer documentation of paytm as well. Mentioning the version for your reference here as well

```
implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.5.3'
```